# how to join a road network into as few lines as possible?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I am processing a polyline file that contains multiple lines representing city roads. I would like to join the lines together into as few lines as possible. I've tried using the 'join multiple lines' plugin, but that creates additional lines that I do not want. Is there a way to only join all the lines that have the exact same endpoint/startpoint?

For context, I'm printing the vector file to a laser engraver. Unfortunately the laser engraver draws the lines in a (seemingly) random order, resulting in a very long print time (hours). I am trying to join the lines together to force the printer to draw connected lines in a logical order. I've tried the 'merge' command, but this hasn't worked because it doesn't change the order of the actual nodes.

I am using QGIS but am open to using other open source software to solve this problem.

[image: Original roads in individual segments]
Figure 1: Original roads in individual segments

[image: roads after using 'Join Multiple Lines' plugin]
Figure 2: Roads after using 'Join Multiple Lines' plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Join Multiple Lines` plugin should be able to do what you need:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/joinmultiplelines/

You can install it in QGIS via `Plugins` --> `Manage and Install Plugins`

**Edit:**

To avoid the added extra lines that `Join Multiple Lines` produces you can simply `Clip` (`Vector > Geoprocessing > Clip...`) the output of `Join Multiple Lines` with the original line layer. This should remove all of the additional lines, but retain the "single feature" quality of the `Join Multiple Lines` output.

Comment: the 'Join Multiple Lines' adds extra lines when two endpoints don't connect. It is very time consuming to delete these extra lines when dealing with a large road network.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a suggestions of how to deal with the extra lines -- let me know if it suffices for what you're after!

Comment: Yes, the clipping worked. I didn't know you could clip a polyline with another polyline like that. thanks

Comment: I didn't either... but figured I'd give it a try. We both learned something today!